# Issue with PHP select/search

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm building a search site where there is a PHP/ mySQL search and a javascript "show this number of results per page" HTML select which is submitted with the number per page that the user desires and then refreshes the search page. Unfortunately, when I loaded the page I got three errors. With the `if (isset($_POST['select'])){ $total_pages == $_POST['select'];}` just set to `$total_pages = 12` it works fine?

- Notice: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
  corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
  near '' at line 1 in /Users/Me/Sites/mySite/search.php on line 36
- Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/Me/Sites/mySite/search.php on line 37
- Warning: Division by zero in /Users/Me/Sites/mySite/search.php on line 104

Here is the code:

```
<?php

    $q = mysql_real_escape_string(ucfirst(trim($_REQUEST['searchquery'])));

        if (isset($q)){
        if (isset($_GET['page'])) $page = $_GET['page']; else $page = 1;
        if (isset($_POST['select'])){ $total_pages == $_POST['select'];} //Here edit the amount per page 
        $record_start = ($page * $total_pages) - $total_pages;
            REQUIRE('config.php');

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM companies WHERE company_name LIKE '%$q%' OR company_description LIKE '%$q%' OR cat1 LIKE '%$q' OR cat2 LIKE '%$q' OR cat3 LIKE '%$q' OR company_phone LIKE '%$q' ORDER by company_name LIMIT $record_start,$total_pages") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
            $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

            $total_results = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as Num FROM companies"),0); 
            echo "
            <h4>Search for &quot;$q&quot;</h4>
             <div class='right'>
                <div class='textad1'>
                    <center>

                        <form name='form1' method='post'>
                            Results per Page:
                            <select name='select' onChange='document.form1.submit()'>
                                <option value='10'";if($_REQUEST['select'] == 12) {echo "selected='selected'";} echo">12</option>
                                <option value='15'";if($_REQUEST['select'] == 18) {echo "selected='selected'";} echo">18</option>
                                <option value='25'";if($_REQUEST['select'] == 32) {echo "selected='selected'";} echo">32</option>
                            </select>
                        </form>

                   </center>
                </div>
                <div class='divider'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='left'>

            <ul>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

If you need any more code, I will quickly get you that. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you connecting to a database prior to executing queries? If not, there's your issue for the mysql errors.

Comment: So you've written 100 lines of code and didn't even try to run it in the process? You cannot write 100 lines without errors at a time - you perform smaller steps, and check if code runs as expected after each line added

Comment: @Vulcan I have a db connect before this I just didn't post, as well as a place where I define $q... I could post if you think it would help?

Comment: @the_ That would definitely be useful, since your mysql query is one of the points of error, and it uses $q several times.

Comment: @zerkms What implies I didn't run the code?

Comment: @the_: the fact that you have several errors at different lines. If you checked it after every line you've written - you would only have one error. And even more - you would definitely know what exactly caused that

Comment: @Vulcan, I just added where I declare the $q, hope it helps!

Comment: @zerkms, I've ran the code many times, it works fine without the if (isset($_POST['select'])){ $total_pages == $_POST['select'];} but with it, it gives three errors

Comment: @the_: `$total_pages == $_POST['select'];` --- what do you think this means? This line doesn't change anything and it **cannot** change anything in the code execution

Comment: @zerkms: I'm sorry, I'm pretty new at php...I don't understand why that doesn't work. Doesn't the $total_pages just become whatever the value of $_POST['select'] is?

Comment: @the_: perform `var_dump($total_pages);` and see Tip: `=` and `==` are different operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should be like this,

```
require('config.php');
$q = mysql_real_escape_string(ucfirst(trim($_REQUEST['searchquery'])));

    if (isset($q)){
    if (isset($_GET['page'])) $page = $_GET['page']; else $page = 1;
    if (isset($_POST['select'])){ $total_pages = $_POST['select'];} //Here edit the amount per page 
    $record_start = ($page * $total_pages) - $total_pages;

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM companies WHERE company_name LIKE '%$q%' OR company_description LIKE '%$q%' OR cat1 LIKE '%$q' OR cat2 LIKE '%$q' OR cat3 LIKE '%$q' OR company_phone LIKE '%$q' ORDER by company_name LIMIT $record_start,$total_pages") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        $total_results = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as Num FROM companies"),0); 

//code continuation
```